# Remove one character without removing all of same characters

Tags: vba

So, I need some help from removing one character without removing all of them.
For example, I want to remove "x" but I don't want to remove all of "x" letter what does a text contain. I made code but it removes all "x" letters from a text.

```
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "x" "")
```

Comment: It would help to provide some examples of input and expected output. You don't want to remove all instances, but what *do* you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VBA `Replace` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function) has a few more optional arguments which you could use: *start* and *count*. If you only want to replace the first occurrence do:

```
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "x", "", 1, 1)
```